Microsoft Graph API returns question marks for non ascii names
I am seeing an issue where the display name returned by the list rules API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/mailfolder-list-messagerules?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) is a string of question marks and spaces when the name of the message rule is non ascii
Example JSON:
{'@odata.id': "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/Users('user_id')/MailFolders('inbox')/MessageRules('message_rule_id')",
   'Id': 'message_rule_id',
   'DisplayName': '???????????????',
   'Description': "If the message was received from 'abc@def.com', move the message to folder '測試' and stop processing more rules on this message.",
   'Sequence': 24,
   'IsEnabled': True,
   'HasError': False,
   'IsReadOnly': False,
   'Conditions': {'FromAddresses': [{'EmailAddress': {'Name': 'abc@def.com',
       'Address': 'abc@def.com'}}]},
   'Actions': {'MoveToFolder': 'folder_id',
    'StopProcessingRules': True}}

I tried both the legacy office API endpoint and the new graph endpoint and both have the same problem. In the legacy office API I can see the non ascii characters in the description of the message rule returned correctly as unicode so it would appear that the encoding issue only appears for certain fields.
